# CSS3 execute animation on scroll without javascript

Tags: css, web, styles

is there a way to execute a CSS3 animation on a scroll event or at a specified scroll height ?

Comment: I'm afraid that it's still not possible… javascript is IMHO only chance.

Comment: @iiic kay, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

not possible, atm. and some text fill the min. characters